# What is this lever in Argentinian toilets?

Tags: identify-this, hygiene, argentina, toilets

I've seen it in some places in Buenos Aires, Argentina. It's not used for flushing the toilet, there's a separate button for that.
[image: toilet lever]

Comment: It's for those poor sods who don't carry their own travel washlets... :) Totally SFW video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBAY1GWjjaQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a water spray, it acts as a "bidet", used to  wash your private area after doing your business.

Similar to this in function:

[image]

Comment: I doubt that it is that. Looks more like a 'smell-good-liquid' injector.

Comment: @Aganju nope, I have used a toilet with the same photo posted by the OP myself.